# Stof Doctrine Extensions - Translatable - Default Locale

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Im struggling with Stof Doctrine Extensions - Translatable for Symfony2. It works fine but I want for my default locale to get data from the original entity, not from the ext_translations. If I don't need it I don't want to make extra queries to get this translations.

Is this possible to achieve that and If yes how I can make it ?

Answer (score 1):

Getting the data from the original entity for the default locale does not seem to me like a good practice to begin with, considering that you may want to be able to change the default locale later.

Comment: Maybe in most of the case you will be right but in my project this is what I need for make application work as fast as it can for default locale.